# How do I monitor bandwidth used by rails apps?

Tags: apache-2.2, bandwidth, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, mod-cband

I run a server that hosts several small rails apps, and I want to track how much bandwidth each is using.

They are all running on Apache 2.2 and Passenger 3.

I used `mod_cband` for static sites, but this doesn't seem to work with passenger.

Is there a good way to track the bandwidth used by different apps? All I need is a breakdown of GB used - no graphs or hooks or API.

Thanks!

Comment: Need the same. Do by this way: [bandwidth management with rails?][1]
All using only the Rails App.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226856/bandwidth-management-with-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the httpd.conf file, if you have your CustomLog set to "combined" (which includes %I and %O for in/out sizes) then it tells you the size of each request.

to get all in/out, run:

```
cat access_log.1297296000 |awk '{ incoming += $(NF - 2) ; outgoing += $(NF - 1) } END { printf("in=%s out=%s\n",incoming,outgoing) }'
```

to get just a specific app, you could run:

```
grep /myapp1 access_log.1297296000 |awk '{ incoming += $(NF - 2) ; outgoing += $(NF - 1) } END { printf("in=%s out=%s\n",incoming,outgoing) }'
```

Comment: Nice workaround :) Had my head stuck in the `mod_cband` approach